# scala: pick right override method for the partially applied function

Tags: scala, function, overload-resolution, partial-application

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).reduce(math.max)  // ok: gives 3
Seq[Long](1, 2, 3).reduce(math.max) // error: type mismatched
                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Why it cannot deduce the `Long` version of `math.max`?

```
Seq[Long](1, 2, 3).reduce(math.max(_:Long, _:Long)) // ok: gives 3L
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Above can solve the problem, but is there any short/clean way to tell the compiler to select `Long` version of `math.max`?

Comment: `Seq[Long](1,2,3).reduce(math.max(_: Long, _))` also works.

Comment: `Seq[Long](1,2,3).reduce[Long](math.max)` also works.

Comment: `Seq[Long](1 2,3).reduce(_ max _)` also works.

Comment: And, of course, `Seq[Long](1, 2, 3).max` also works, but now we're drifting away from the OP's real question.